# tkinter: Making a 3x3 grid with an image

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I have these lines of code:

```
def initialize_board(self):
    for i in range(2):
        self.canvas.create_line((i + 1) * size / 3, 0, (i + 1) * size / 3, size)

    for i in range(2):
        self.canvas.create_line(0, (i + 1) * size / 3, size, (i + 1) * size / 3)
```

This makes two vertical lines and two horizontal lines.
But I want to replace it with a 3x3 grid of an image of a square to represent the same thing. I'm making a tic tac toe game for reference.

This is the image I want to use:

```
self.empty_image = PhotoImage(file = 'book/pybook/image/empty.gif')
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Simply use two-levels for loops (for loop inside for loop) and `self.canvas.create_image(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display images on a `Canvas` you need to create a separate `Canvas` [image object](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_image.html) for each one (in addition to a `BitmapImage` or `Photoimage` widget). Laying them out in a grid can easily be accomplish via nested `for` loops — one iterating each row and the other each column in a row.

Note how the integer ID number of the image object that's returned from each `Canvas.create_image()` call gets stored in a list-of-lists named `self.board`. Saving them this way will allow the `image` attribute of the associated `Canvas` image object to be changed later as the game is being played (via the [`itemconfigure()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas-methods.html) `Canvas` graphical object method).

Below is an example of implementing it as described.

```
import tkinter as tk
WHITE = '#ffffff'

class Game:
    EMPTY_CELL_IMAGE_FILE_PATH = './ttt_empty.gif'

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.empty_cell_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=self.EMPTY_CELL_IMAGE_FILE_PATH)
        self.width = 3 * self.empty_cell_image.width()
        self.height = 3 * self.empty_cell_image.height()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(parent, width=self.width, height=self.height,
                                background=WHITE)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.initialize_board()

    def initialize_board(self):
        self.board = [[None for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]  # Pre-allocate.
        width, height = self.empty_cell_image.width(), self.empty_cell_image.height()
        empty_cell_image = self.empty_cell_image
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                self.board[i][j] = self.canvas.create_image(i*width, j*height,
                                                            anchor='nw',
                                                            image=empty_cell_image)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Tic-Tac-Toe')
    game = Game(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot showing display of empty board]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a tic tac toe game you would be better off creating a 3x3 grid of buttons, then displaying the image of the X/O on the button.

Either way, your best bet is to create the widget and then call it onto the canvas with the grid method.

See [Python grid() method in Tkinter](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-grid-method-in-tkinter/).

Comment: "Either way" isn't correct because you can't call the `grid()` geometry manager method on `Canvas` graphical objects created via `Canvas.create_image()` for instance.